# How to set minimum size character for Script input form?

Tags: javascript, php

Here i have call fields like this so i have to  mention validation for this how can i do it ? now no validation but i want make minimum character 8 ??

```
[ "note", {"label":" Reason why not apply leave before taken","type":"textarea","validation":"none"}]
```

i have a fileds sepratly text, textarea, date, datetime etc....

below sample validation for email

```
[ "work_email", {"label":"Work Email","type":"text","validation":"email"}],
```

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: Did you try minlength: 6 ?

Comment: ya it won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the validation of HTML5. like,

```html
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input pattern=".{8,}" required="required"> <!-- required attribute will make the text box not empty check and pattern attribute is checking for Minimum 8 character -->
  <input type="submit" value="Check">
  </form>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my php file i used

```
if(strlen($req->note) < 6){
            return new IceResponse(IceResponse::ERROR,"Please provide the correct reason");
        }
```